# How to sort a list by two values?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I need help with a sorting algorithm.

I have a list of foods. Each food has 2 nutrients.

[image]

I want to sort this list in a way in which, at the top should be the foods that has the greatest `N High` nutrient, but at the same time, the lowest `N Low` nutrient. The priority is `N High`, but `N Low` matters too. Look at that example. If only we would sort by `N High`, then `Food 2` will be the first and `Food 3` will be the second. But also taking into account `N Low`, the foods swich places, because it is better to have a food with 27g less from the unwanted nutrient `N Low`, at the expense of only 8g from the good nutrient `N High`. I don't know if I explained well...

I know how to sort the list, but I need only one value made from those two nutrients... and I don't know how to do that.

Thanks !

Comment: You need to adequately define your objective function, see [Mathematical Optimization on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization).  In essence, you need to specify "How much `N High` matters compared to `N Low`"

Comment: You would have to come up with a function of the two values, that outputs a single number out; and then sort according to that value. My suggestion would be to choose
$$
f(\text{N high}, \text{N low}) = \text{N high} - \text{N low}
$$
You can try out other functions, too, and see what you can come up with.

Comment: It could be that you want to look at sorting on a newly created column `N High - N Low`.  Maybe you want to sort on a column where the weights of these are different, say for example `2 * N High - N Low`.,  That is entirely up to you to decide and we cannot decide for you.

Comment: Indeed. Nor do I know exactly what I want... :( But that last formula it seems to be arranging them in a somewhat right order...

Comment: The reason you do not know exactly what you want is that you have not examined your situation carefully enough. This is not a mathematical issue, it is in how you are using mathematics to model your real world situation. If possible, you need to carefully examine the information available to you to figure out just how important N High is in comparison to N Low. That will lead you to the most appropriate way to combine them into a single quantity you can sort on. If you cannot gather enough information to figure this out, then you have to make an educated guess, such as their difference.